# Does PyCharm have the feature for executing python script in parts/cells (like in VsCode - Run in interacting Window)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ipython

when using **VSCode**, I can run python files in cells/parts as if it was Jupyter notebook, without actually having a notebook.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py
It means, you can run a python file, part by part, iteratively, like in Jupyter Notebooks, but in `.py` file.

it helps me to keep the code organized as a python file. (screenshot attached)

I wonder if the same feature exists in **PyCharm**. I couldn't find it.

I attach a screenshot of the feature in VsCode when I can run simple python file in interactive mode, part by part.

thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, answer found:

Magic Python in PyCharm
PyCharm supports Magic Python cell execution. To use Magic Python, you need to enable Scientific Mode in the View menu. You can then use `#%%` to indicate the start and end of cells. Individual Cells can be executed in the console by pressing CTRL+Enter.

In PyCharm, right-click on the root directory and select New > Python File. Give your file a meaningful name.
Enter

```
#%%
print("This is the first cell")
#%%
print("This is not executed when the first cell is run")
```

Enable Scientific Mode in the View menu.
Run the first cell by placing you mouse in the cell and pressing CTRL+Enter.
Run the second cell by clicking on the Play button (arrow) that appears in the gutter of the editor.

[image]

source(and credit to):
https://www.kevinsheppard.com/teaching/python/course/lesson-1/

Comment: By the way, `#%%` is called magic commands, you can use it in vscode as well.

Answer (score 2):

The same feature exists in PyCharm.

Just right-click and select Execute selection in Python Console.

[image: Selection]

[image: Execution]

Comment: it's not the same feature, this one just runs the selected code. it does not create "cells" like in Jupyter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).